# Issue with print to pdf rotation

Tags: windows-7, print-to-pdf

I am printing to pdf in Windows 7.  Lately, my documents rotate when printing.  They are in landscape format before printing, but the printed document rotates 90 degrees.  How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

This can most likely be changed in the printer preferences. Click `File > Print...`, then click `Preferences` in the printing dialog. That opens a printer-specific configuration dialog. You should be able to change the page orientation there.

Comment: Can you please expand this answer? Describe where to go to change it, why that option is there, maybe add screen shots? Generic answers like this should be avoided as we are trying to cater to the simplest of users with advice from the most professional of users